# Is it possible to create a ListView using run()?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, runnable

I would like to know if it is possible to create a list view in runnable using something like this ? Could someone please give me an example to do it? Thank you.

```
public void testBtnListViewClick(View v) {
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
    public void run() {
       LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
       ListView lv = new ListView(this);
       String[] values = new String[10];
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
          values[i] = ""+i;
       }
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, values);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+arg2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.d("DEBUG", ""+arg2);
            }
        });
        //ll.addView(lv);
        ll.addView(lv, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        setContentView(ll);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ..you can..`runOnUiThread()` which runs in the main thread.In android UI changes like `Views` can be modiied or added only in UI thread..Its in the UI thread so no problem for yours..

inside that this refers to runnable object..so change these lines

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, values);
```

into

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
ListView lv = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, values);
```

Comment: but it will wont allow me to add this line  LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
       ListView lv = new ListView(this); ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, values);

Comment: what its saying??is any exception??

Comment: its underlined red color on the line "new LinearLayout(this);" , "new LinearLayout(this);" and "new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, values);" and when i hover over it each of them, it says  "The constructor LinearLayout(new Runnable(){}) is undefined" , "The constructor LinearLayout(new Runnable(){}) is undefined" and this "The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new Runnable(){}, int, String[]) is undefined", and that is what made me wondering if i can use it inside runnable